Why is TeXbook exercise 20.16 difficult?
TeXbook, paragraph before exercise 20.14:

Suppose, for example, that you want to define \a to be equal to \b (expanded) followed by \c (not expanded) followed by \d (expanded), assuming that \b and \d are simple macros without parameters. There are two easy ways to do it:

[...]
TeXbook exercise 20.14

Figure out a way to define \a as in the previous paragraph, without using TeX's primitives \noexpand and \the.

TeXbook's answer to exercise 20.14

One idea is to say
\let\save=\c \let\c=0 \edef\a{\b\c\d} \let\c=\save
because control sequences equivalent to characters are not expandable. However, this doesn’t expand occurrences of \c that might be present in the expansions of \b and \d.
Another way, which is free of this defect, is
\edef\next#1#2{\def#1{\b#2\d}} \next\a\c
(and it’s worth a close look!).

TeXbook exercise 20.15

Continuing the example of expansion avoidance, suppose that you want to expand \b completely until only unexpandable tokens are left, but you don’t want to expand \c at all, and you want to expand \d only one level. For example, after \def\b{\c\c} and \def\c{*} and \def\d{\b\c} the goal would be to get the effect of \def\a{**\c\b\c}. How can such a partial expansion be achieved, using \the?

TeXbook exercise 20.16

Solve the previous exercise without \the or \noexpand. (This is difficult.)

Why is TeXbook exercise 20.16 difficult?
Given definitions without hashes, e.g.,
\def\b{\c\c} \def\c{*} \def\d{\b\c}
, you can easily do along what in the TeXbook is presented as the "solution free of defect" to exercise 20.14:
\long\edef\next#1#2#3{\def#2{\b#3#1}}
\expandafter\next\expandafter{\d}\a\c
% If you want to be nice to the hash table, use \a instead of \next.
%
% You could also do:
%
% \long\edef\next#1#2{\def#2{\b#1}}
% \expandafter\next\expandafter{\expandafter\c\d}\a

\show\a

\csname stop\endcsname
\bye

This is without \the and without \noexpand and without \halign.
(The latter was requested in exercise 1 of Michael Downes, ‘Around the Bend’, a summary of internet discussion which took place under his guidance primarily at the INFO-TEX list, but also at comp.text.tex (usenet) and via private email. Online archived at http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/challenges/AroBend/AroundTheBend.pdf.)
Of course, anything requiring to expand an interim-macro defined via \edef leads to reducing hashes contained in the ⟨balanced text⟩ of the ⟨definition⟩ of the interim-macro. This is taken into account neither with this solution, nor with the answer provided in the TeXbook, which does \vbox-\halign-\span-in-preamble-trickery instead, nor with the answers of ‘Around the Bend’‑exercise 1.
Also full expansion of \b should not lead to the carrying out of brace-hacks resulting in unbalanced braces.
Am I overlooking an error of mine, e.g., a category of edge cases where the approach presented here would fail?

Not entirely sure, but maybe this exercise was written before \expandafter? AFAIK, \expandafter was an addition to TeX not present in the first versions.

@Skillmon No, \noexpand (25 May 1983) was added later than \expandafter (12 Sep 1982); see Knuth's errorlog. I see a typo in the exercise: replace \noexpand by \expandafter.

@UdoWermuth thanks for enlightening me :)

I think you miss the main point here. It is not that ``difficult'' is
wrong, the error is somewhere else.
I surmise the text of the exercise 20.16 should be:
Solve the previous exercise without |\the| or |\expandafter|.\ (This is difficult.)
It seems that Knuth was still influenced by exercise 20.14 when he
formulated exercise 20.16: He made a typo and exchanged two
primitives. Exercise 20.15 does not use \noexpand but \the and
\expandafter. So it makes sense to exclude them in exercise 20.16.
With the above text it becomes clear why Knuth uses for this exercise
an \halign solution and why he calls the exercise ``difficult''.

I think you miss the main point of the question: I never said that "difficult" is wrong. And of course it is obvious that \expandafter is not used.
